# Create dummy variables frame pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, bigdata

I have a spark data frame like:

```
|---------------------|------------------------------|
|       Brand         |       Model                  |
|---------------------|------------------------------|
|       Hyundai       |  Elentra,Creta               |
|---------------------|------------------------------|
|       Hyundai       |  Creta,Grand i10,Verna       |
|---------------------|------------------------------|
|       Maruti        |  Eritga,S-cross,Vitara Brezza|
|---------------------|------------------------------|
|       Maruti        |  Celerio,Eritga,Ciaz         |
|---------------------|------------------------------|
```

I want a data frame like this:

```
|---------------------|---------|--------|--------------|--------|---------|
|       Brand         | Model0  | Model1 | Model2       | Model3 | Model4  |
|---------------------|---------|--------|--------------|--------|---------|
|       Hyundai       | Elentra | Creta  | Grand i10    | Verna  |  null   |
|---------------------|---------|--------|--------------|--------|---------|
|       Maruti        | Ertiga  | S-Cross| Vitara Brezza| Celerio|  Ciaz   |
|---------------------|---------|--------|--------------|--------|---------|
```

I have used this code :

```
schema = StructType([
    StructField("Brand", StringType()),StructField("Model", StringType())])
tempCSV = spark.read.csv("PATH\\Cars.csv", sep='|', schema=schema)

tempDF = tempCSV.select(
        "Brand",
        f.split("Model", ",").alias("Model"),
        f.posexplode(f.split("Model", ",")).alias("pos", "val")
    )\
    .drop("val")\
    .select(
        "Brand",
        f.concat(f.lit("Model"),f.col("pos").cast("string")).alias("name"),
        f.expr("Model[pos]").alias("val")
    )\
    .groupBy("Brand").pivot("name").agg(f.first("val")).toPandas()
```

But I'm not getting the desired result. Instead of giving the second table result its giving :

```
|---------------------|---------|--------|--------------|
|       Brand         | Model0  | Model1 | Model2       |
|---------------------|---------|--------|--------------|
|       Hyundai       | Elentra | Creta  | Grand i10    |
|---------------------|---------|--------|--------------|
|       Maruti        | Ertiga  | S-Cross| Vitara Brezza|
|---------------------|---------|--------|--------------|
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Two questions: 1) Does the order matter? 2) Do you know the maximum number of models ahead of time?

Comment: no the order dosen't matter. Also we don't know the maximum number of models. but we can assume and then delete the column with all null values. @pault

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you are pivoting data on `pos` which has the repeat value in the same brand group.
You can use the `rownumber()` and pivot your data to generate the desired result.

Here are the sample code on top of the data you have provided.

```
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([('Hyundai',"Elentra,Creta"),("Hyundai","Creta,Grand i10,Verna"),("Maruti","Eritga,S-cross,Vitara Brezza"),("Maruti","Celerio,Eritga,Ciaz")],("Brand","Model"))

tmpDf = df.select("Brand",f.split("Model", ",").alias("Model"),f.posexplode(f.split("Model", ",")).alias("pos", "val"))

tmpDf.createOrReplaceTempView("tbl")

seqDf = sqlContext.sql("select Brand, Model, pos, val, row_number() over(partition by Brand order by pos) as rnk from tbl")

seqDf.groupBy('Brand').pivot('rnk').agg(f.first('val'))
```

This will generate following result.

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+---------+-------------+----+                  
|  Brand|      1|      2|      3|        4|            5|   6|
+-------+-------+-------+-------+---------+-------------+----+
| Maruti| Eritga|Celerio|S-cross|   Eritga|Vitara Brezza|Ciaz|
|Hyundai|Elentra|  Creta|  Creta|Grand i10|        Verna|null|
+-------+-------+-------+-------+---------+-------------+----+
```

Comment: I'm getting this error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'resource'". Is it due to spark version. I'm using 2.4.0  @HiteshRaval

Comment: @Tarun You might need to import the packages, 
`from pyspark.sql import *`

`from pyspark.sql import functions as f`

I am also using the same spark version 2.4.0 I have executed this code snippet on AWS EMR - pyspark console.

Comment: Great, @Tarun if the posted answer is relevant and helped you to get the desired result then please up-vote and accept the answer. Thanks